# TCP Listener Stop Listening In Windows Form

Tags: c#

I am working on Tcp connection to send messages between two pc it work fine in console application case but in Windows Form the listener is stop to listen it does not listen continuously and throw this exception.

Exception:

```
Not listening. you must call the start() method before calling this method.
```

Here is my code.

Code:

```
        public static  void TcpListener()
    {


            TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {


                // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
                Int32 port = 8888;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(Getlocalip());

            // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;

            // Enter the listening loop.


            Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Waiting for a connection... ");

                    // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                    // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
      TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    MessageBox.Show("Server Connected!");

                    data = null;

                    // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                    int i;

                    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        // Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
                        if (data == "pbrush")
                        {
                            Runprocess("start " + data);

                            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data + " opened successfully");

                            // Send back a response.
                            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);

                        }
                        if (data == "calc")
                        {
                            Runprocess("start " + data);

                            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data + " opened successfully");

                            // Send back a response.
                            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        }

                        if (data.ToString() == "getmac")
                        {
                            string result = Runprocess(data, true);

                            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result);

                            // Send back a response.
                            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        }

                        if (data.ToString() == "tree d:")
                        {
                            string result = Runprocess(data, true);

                            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result);

                            // Send back a response.
                            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        }



                        if (data.ToString() == "ipconfig")
                        {
                            string result = Runprocess(data, true);

                            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result);

                            // Send back a response.
                            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        }
                        if (data.ToString() == "facebook")
                        {
                            Runprocess("start " + data);

                            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data + " opened successfully");

                            // Send back a response.
                            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        }
                        // Process the data sent by the client.
                        data = data.ToUpper();

                        Console.WriteLine("Sent");
                    }

                    // Shutdown and end connection
                    client.Close();
                }

            });
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();

        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            server.Stop();
        }


        Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
        Console.Read();








    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very simple - You are calling the `server.Stop()` in the finally block. And since in the try block you are just starting a thread, it immediately skips to the finally block.

You are, indeed, waiting for a key in the console but that's already after you've stopped the server.

So, first you should add a try-catch block inside the thread, because currently you won't be catching any exceptions that occurs there.

Second, move the `Console.Read()` before the  `server.Stop()`.

Comment: After adding try catch inside thread i got this exception A blocking operation was interupted by call to WSACancelblockingCall.

Comment: That is ok, it means that you were waiting in the `server.AcceptTcpClient()` while you called the `server.Stop()`

Comment: Make sure you are waiting for the key **before** stopping the server

Comment: But after exception the control goes to finally block the if I wait here then after key press it will automatically go out.

Comment: No. The finally block is reached before the exception. You need to decide about the flow of the program, when and why to exit is up to you. you can leave the server.stop to the point when you are exiting the application.